# How to apply SearchDirection to Find first occurrence?

Tags: excel, vba, find

In MS Excel I have VBA code that looks in a range to find days in a month.

Range goes like 1,2,3,...,30,1 (*in columns*) since some months have 30 days while some have 31.

When trying to find "1" in the range the code always give the second "1" as a result.

When I delete the second "1" from the range it gives the correct result.

"SearchDirection" seems do nothing in this situation.

```vb
day = 1
Set findday = findmonth.Find(day, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
Debug.Print findday.Address
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find Method 'Failure'

- If you use `xlValues` with the `LookIn` argument, then if the row or column where you expect to find the value is hidden, `Find` will 'fail' to find it.
- By default the `Find` method uses `xlNext` for `SearchDirection` so you can omit it.
- Your issue is most certainly the omitting of the `After` argument.
  The thing is that if you enter the first cell (`A1`) as the parameter for the `After` argument (which is by default (`A1`)), the search will start from `A2` if `xlByColumns` or `B1` if `xlByRows`. Therefore you have to specify the last cell in the range for the `Find` method to start the search with the first cell in the range (`A1`).

For example:

```
Day = 1
Set findday = findmonth.Find( _
    What:=Day, _
    After:=findmonth.Cells(findmonth.Rows.Count, findmonth.Columns.Count), _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext)
Debug.Print findday.Address
```

Or if you prefer one row:

```
Dim findday As Range
Day = 1
Set findday = findmonth.Find(What:=Day, After:=findmonth.Cells(findmonth.Rows.Count, findmonth.Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
Debug.Print findday.Address
```

Using the `With` statement you could make it more readable:

```
Day = 1
With findmonth
    Set findday = .Find(What:=Day, After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
End With
Debug.Print findday.Address
```

Comment: Fyi a shorter way to refer to the last cell in a range is `.Cells(.Count)`

Comment: @chris neilsen: I don't like it, but if you insist you might use `.Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)` to make sure that `.Count` doesn't fail.